# Why am i getting OCI-30757 during `getVector` in my `readSQL` method?

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I'm upgrading our application to use the latest Oracle Instant Client libraries (linux-x64 v21.1.0.0.0), and I'm running into a new exception that we haven't seen before.

```
OCI-30757: Message 30757 not found;  product=RDBMS; facility=OCI
```

It's occurring during a call to `oracle::occi::getVector` in one of our types' `readSQL` methods:

```
void MyType::readSQL(AnyData& stream)
{
    mId = stream.getNumber(); // oracle::occi::Number
    oracle::occi::getVector(stream, mNames); // std::vector<std::string>
}
```

Are there some changes we need to make to our `readSQL` method to support the new occi version?

Here's the callstack:

```
oracle::occi::SQLException::SQLException(oracle::occi::SQLExceptionImpl*)@plt
oracle::occi::SQLExceptionCreate(void*, int)
oracle::occi::ErrorCheck(int, OCIError*)
oracle::occi::getVector(oracle::occi::AnyData const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&)
MyDataType::readSQL(MyDataType * const this, oracle::occi::AnyData & stream)
MyDataType::readSQL(void * ctx)
libclntsh.so.21.1!kodpunp
libclntsh.so.21.1!kokoupkl
kokoicvtgen
kosimgconv
kosicvt
libclntsh.so.21.1!kosibegin
libclntsh.so.21.1!kpctos
ttca2p
ttcacs
ttcdrv
nioqwa
upirtrc
kpurcsc
kpuexec
OCIStmtExecute
oracle::occi::StatementImpl::doOCIExecute()
oracle::occi::StatementImpl::do_execute()
oracle::occi::StatementImpl::executeUpdate(std::string const&)
main(int argc, char ** argv)
```

I'm not even sure why it's calling `readSQL` here, the SP doesn't return an object of that type, and the SP isn't even executed before it crashes.

This works fine with v11 of the occi libs: `readSQL` isn't called, the SP is executed and everything is fine.

Comment: It's quite likely this is an Oracle internal error (the fact that it doesn't have a published message seems fishy). If you have an Oracle Support contract I would suggest trying MOS.

Answer (score 0):

Has the compiler also been updated? What version of compiler is being used?

Comment: Centos7 devtoolset-10: `gcc (GCC) 10.2.1 20200804 (Red Hat 10.2.1-2)`

Comment: actually, my description above is inaccurate. in our real code we had a `timestamp with time zone` column. when we removed that column, the issue was resolved. interestingly the exception was thrown before the timezone column was read...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Which libocci shared library are you using? The default libocci.so is compatible only with g++4.x STLs.

Comment: linux-x64 v21.1.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

OCCI is not certified with gcc10. Certainly not the default libocci.so.21.1. But you can try to use a new library meant to work with g++5/6/7/8. It is named libocci_gcc53.so.21.1 that you see when you install the regular client (21c), not the instant client.